# How to format string with thousands and decimal separators in input field as you type using Angular "number" filter?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter

As you type in the input field, for example: `10000.00` I want to format it as `10,000.00` within the input field itself.

I have the following:

```
  $scope.a = '';
  $scope.addCommas = function(a){
    a = $filter('number')(a,2);
    $scope.b = a;
  }
```

And I can output the correct format in `b` but if I replace the last line with `$scope.a = a` it doesn't work.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="a" ng-change="addCommas(a)">
```

Plnkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/FfmiFrZ0NhFbEkdiQUfW?p=preview

Comment: You could use https://github.com/assisrafael/angular-input-masks

Comment: You can use this also. https://github.com/FCSAmerica/angular-fcsa-number

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a little service to format currency.  https://github.com/bruceradtke/MoneyHelper